# Can't delete corrupt files on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, command-line-interface, hacking, rm

So I got hit by a script kitte...  Fortunately the box is Ubuntu and was able to replace w/ binaries from a comparable system, **however**,

Some of the files I couldn't delete, and am still stumped on this.  The hijacked files are sitting in the `/_bin` directory which is writeable by *root*.

```
nathan@db-0:~$ ls -ld !$
ls -ld /_bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 12 18:00 /_bin
```

Ok, those are the perms on the directory, now for the files within:

```
nathan@db-0:~$ ls -l /_bin
total 268
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  39696 Nov 19 22:25 ls
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 119800 Mar 31  2012 netstat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 101240 Dec 12  2011 ps
```

Now when I try to delete one of these files (as root):

```
root@db-0:/home/nathan# rm /_bin/ls
rm: cannot remove `/_bin/ls': Operation not permitted
```

Or if I try to delete the entire `_bin` directory (again as root):

```
root@db-0:/home/nathan# rm -rf /_bin
rm: cannot remove `/_bin/ls': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove `/_bin/netstat': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove `/_bin/ps': Operation not permitted
```

So how can I delete these files?

Edit:

Sure enough the immutable bit has been set, however, removing it does not let me delete the files.

```
root@db-0:/home/nathan# lsattr /_bin
s---ia--------- /_bin/ls
s---ia--------- /_bin/netstat
s---ia--------- /_bin/ps

root@db-0:/home/nathan# chattr -R -i /_bin
root@db-0:/home/nathan# lsattr /_bin
s----a--------- /_bin/ls
s----a--------- /_bin/netstat
s----a--------- /_bin/ps

root@db-0:/home/nathan# rm -rf /_bin
rm: cannot remove `/_bin/ls': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove `/_bin/netstat': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove `/_bin/ps': Operation not permitted
```

Also verified `/_bin` doesn't have immutable bit:

```
root@db-0:/home/nathan# lsattr -d /_bin
--------------- /_bin
```

Comment: Reinstall the system from scratch, don't try to repair it. You'll be never sure to have eliminated everything.

Comment: Can you do `strace -v rm /_bin/ls` and as it's longer output, put it on the web like pastebin.com?

Comment: I say we take off and nuke the entire site from orbit. It's the only way to be sure. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCbfMkh940Q

Comment: The answer you accepted says there are other extended attributes that might prevent removal... there might also be `/_bin/.*` files with funky attributes.

Comment: Good man @vonbrand, though that wasn't the case here an old colleague once told me of a case where there was a `...` directory - tricky kitty!

Comment: @quickshiftin, we once had a `.. ` (dot dot space) directory full of malware in `/bin`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most likely the attacker has set the immutable attribute on the files and directory. This is commonly done by rootkits to make cleanup more difficult.

To confirm this, try:

```
lsattr /_bin
```

To remove the immutable attribute, use:

```
chattr -R -i /_bin
```

You'll also want to clear the `a` and `s` attributes, since these may affect your ability to remove the files.

```
chattr -R -i -a -s /_bin
```

See the `chattr` man page for a full explanation of what all the attributes are and what they do.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the sticky bit is still there.

```
chmod -t /_bin
```

Comment: That is irrelevant...